# Multiple classes running on same Thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, class, sharing

I have a class, let's call it "Class1", which implements Runnable, and starts a thread, named "thread 1", using thread.start();

I have another class which is a subclass of Class1, called "Class2". It contains the main method, and runs another method in the class which executes a while loop. What I've noticed however, is that the Thread that executes the while loop in Class2 isn't "thread 1", but an entirely different thread.

Is there a way I can make the Class2 while loop execute on "thread 1" instead of its own thread? If I'm being too vague let me know. :) And thanks for any help.

Comment: A thread can run one method at a time. If you want your `while` loop to run in a thread of your runnable, make that thread call the method with the `while` loop.

Comment: please post some of your code, maybe we could give a solution better to you

Comment: Post some code, or your question is likely to get closed. It is very hard to understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple problems I see in your description of your code:

- You should separate out your main class and not have it be in the subclass `Class2`.  Call it `Main` to not be confused.
- You should never start a thread in an object constructor.  This is a very bad pattern since `this` can be accessed by the new thread before it is fully initialized.  I assume the main thread is calling `new Class1()` and `new Class2()`.  Have the main thread also start the threads.

  ```
  Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Class1());
  thread1.start();
  Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Class2());
  thread2.start();
  ```
- There is no way for a thread which is running on `Class1` to access a subclass method.  If you start `new Thread(new Class1())` the thread won't even see any methods in `Class2`.

Maybe I'm not understanding what you are saying.  Post some small code samples so we can better address your issues.